# Spring's WebSecurity 'ignore' still creating sessions

Tags: spring, session, spring-security

I want to avoid creating a session when a user requests static resources like css files.  Howerver, even after telling WebSecurity to ignore this static resource path, I noticed that all of the responses from my SpringBoot application still have the JSESSIONID cookie.  Why?

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/login", "/error").permitAll() 
        .anyRequest().authenticated(); //all other pages require users to be authenticated

}
```

I'm using Spring Security to protect my application.... but for requests to these static resources, I don't want a session created or validated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  It was my fault.  I'm using Spring Security and extended RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter. While web.ignoring()... does avoid all Spring Security authentication/authorization checks, it still does run through the custom filters.

In one of my filters I had the following line:

```
HttpServletRequest req = ((HttpServletRequest) request);
HttpSession session = req.getSession();
```

I use it to check if a session already exists and if I need to refresh it (too complicated to explain here).  But that [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession()), `req.getSession()` will create a new session if it doesn't already exist.  I didn't realize it had that side effect.

Instead, I should be calling: `req.getSession(false)`.  This will return a session if it already exists and return null if it doesn't.